# Java restful webservices - sending response and Id together

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

On user calling my webservice, I am inserting record in database and it generates auto-increment key.
I want to send response in following format :

```
    {
    "status" : "success",
    "autogenerated_id" : 1

    }
```

Following is my code and o/p

```
WsResponse resp = new WsResponse();
resp.setStatus("success");
resp.addData("autogenerated_id", autogenerated_id);
```

Response is :

```
 {
        "status": "success",
        "response": {
            "autogenerated_id": 8
        }
    }
```

What can I change so that I get autogenerated_id at same level as that of status ?
Or can I change the text "response" to anyother text like "data" ?

Comment: Is this WsResponse a class you created? If yes, post it's content.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want and is has a simple reason.
The object you are seeing is the response object related to the HTTP connection (200->OK, 404->Not Found, 500-> Internal Server Error, etc), not the result status coming  from the database procedure.
In addition to this, you can send back whatever you like, however it must be inside the response object.
It Should look like this

```
{
        "status": "success", //result of the connection.
        "response": {
            "status": "success", //result of the db procedure.
            "autogenerated_id": 8
        }
    }
```

The returned object is converted to a  string using different formats and encoding and then it is send back to the client (json in your case).
The client is who turns the string back to an object.
If your are printing the response object, then you can't change it. However, if you are printing the data received from the server, then you can simply return a different object according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, well, can I change the word "response" to anyother thing else such as "data" ?